# How writeToFile in a .playground?

Tags: swift, save, plist, swift-playground

I have edited a `.plist` file. How I understood it: because of sandboxing it is only possible to read files inside the `.playgrounds` file in a `Resources` directory. But how is it possible to write the edited file to this folder?

```
// read file
let xmlPath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist")!
var xmlDictionary: [String : AnyObject] = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: xmlPath) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

// editing file
// ...

// saving file
let saveDict: NSDictionary = xmlDictionary as NSDictionary
let savePath: String = xmlPath.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Saved.plist")
saveDict.writeToFile(savePath, atomically: false) // ~> false
```

Whether `savePath` nor `xmlPath` is working, returns `false` meaning *no success*.

It would be nice if I could replace the old (non-edited) version of the `.plist` file, but saving to a new file would also be ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

modifying files in the main bundle doesn't appear to be possible, [see earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589250/write-in-main-bundle-directory-is-it-allowed). What you can do is to save to the sandboxed application folders, the URLs for which can be retrieved like this:

```
 func applicationDirectory(directory:NSSearchPathDirectory) -> NSURL? {

    var appDirectory:String?
    var paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(directory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true);
    if paths.count > 0 {
        if let pathString = paths[0] as? String {
            appDirectory = pathString
        }
    }
    if let dD = appDirectory {
        return NSURL(string:dD)
    }
    return nil
}



func applicationTemporaryDirectory() -> NSURL? {

    if let tD = NSTemporaryDirectory() {
        return NSURL(string:tD)
    }

    return nil

}

applicationTemporaryDirectory()

applicationDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory)
```

The urls will display in the righthand side of the playground, then simply copy and paste into the Finder -> Go -> Go to Folder dialogue box.

**GitHub Repo:** For a full working example see this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sketchytech/SwiftFiles).

Answer (score 1):

You can.

Use your current `plist` as a template by looking at its source code.

[image]

Then assign it to a string

```
let newPlist: String = 
"""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2020 YourName. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>NSMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>NSSupportsAutomaticTermination</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSSupportsSuddenTermination</key>
    <true/>
    <key>TDAMERITRADE_API_KEY</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>ACCOUNT_ID</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <string>YourName.YourProjName</string>
</dict>
</plist>
"""
```

Then call the write method on strings using filePath for the url.

```
let url: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/username/Desktop/iOS/YourProj/YourProj/info.plist")
newPlist.write(to: url, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```